# How to make Custom Pull to refresh for recyclerView? (Not Swipe to refresh)

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I need this custom pull-down to refresh layout. How Can I develop this for Android?
Please make sure I want exactly this behavior, not Android native swipe to refresh.

[image]

Comment: There are [many open source pull to refresh implementations](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/78), in addition to Google's own open source `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Examine their implementations and see how they approach the problem, and use that to derive your own solution if none of the existing ones match your needs.

Answer (score -1):

**First of all add:**

```
implementation androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0
```

to your **gradle file**

**XML file**

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

//Add here your views
// I've got a RecyclerView so for what I need height is 0dp

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_main)

    /* you probably have a few 
    code lines here*/
    initRefreshListener()
}
.
.
.
  private fun initRefreshListener() {

    val swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.refreshLayout)

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show() // totally optional
        // call API or what have you here
        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this before, it will show a default behaviour with the default round progress bar. I want a stretching effect as I have shown in the GIF